# Difference between node and operations

Tags: tensorflow

I cannot understand what is the difference between node and operations in Tensorflow.

For example:

```
with open('myfile_1','w') as myfile:
     for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node:
         myfile.write(n.name+'\n')



with open('myfile_2','w') as myfile:
     for op in tf.get_default_graph().get_operations():
         myfile.write(op.name+'\n')
```

what goes into myfile_1 and what goes into myfile_2 ? and Variables to which class/file belong?

Can we call "Tensors" all of them ? I am a bit confused about nomenclature here...

I add here, following the suggestion in the comments, the result on a simple graph:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
x=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[1])
y=2*x
z=tf.constant(3.0,dtype=tf.float32)
w=tf.get_variable('w',[2,3], initializer = tf.zeros_initializer())

with open('myfile_1','w') as myfile:
     for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node:
         myfile.write(n.name+'\n')

with open('myfile_2','w') as myfile:
     for op in tf.get_default_graph().get_operations():
         myfile.write(op.name+'\n')

with tf.Session() as sess:
     print(sess.run(y,feed_dict={x : [3]}))
```

In this case myfile_1 and myfile_2 are both equal to:

```
Placeholder
mul/x
mul
Const
w/Initializer/zeros
w
w/Assign
w/read
```

Comment: What's the output if you run this on a simple graph?

Comment: I've run it into a more complicated program and could not get insight. The files had a lot in common. Now I try a simpler example and add the result.

Answer (score 3):

Tensorflow graph is a directed graph such that:

- Nodes - operations (ops).
- Directed edges - tensors.

For example, when you define:

```py
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 2))
```

`x` is a Tensor and it is the output of the `Placeholder` op:

```py
print(x.op.type) # Placeholder
```

`as_graph_def()` returns SERIALIZED version (think of it as a text version) of the graph. `get_operation()` returns the actual operations, not their serialized representation. When you print these operations (or write them to a file) you get the same values because the `__str__()` method of the operation returns its serialized form.

You're not going to get always the same values. For example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
tf.reset_default_graph()

v = tf.Variable(np.random.normal([1]))
res1, res2 = [], []

for n in v.graph.as_graph_def(add_shapes=False).node:
    res1.append(n.__str__())

for op in tf.get_default_graph().get_operations():
    res2.append(op.__str__())
print(set(res1) == set(res2)) # True <-- exact same representation
res1, res2 = [], []

for n in v.graph.as_graph_def(add_shapes=True).node:
    res1.append(n.__str__())

for op in tf.get_default_graph().get_operations():
    res2.append(op.__str__())
print(set(res1) == set(res2)) # False <-- not the same in this case!
```

For more you could refer to the original tensorflow [paper](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/osdi16/osdi16-abadi.pdf).

Comment: Thanks! (also for the reference to the tensorflow paper). But so this means that myfile_1 and myfile_2 are always the same ?  And therefore nodes and operations are synonimous ?

Comment: I appended something to my answer to clarify why do you get the same results. Operations are more higher level. In the implementation `_NodeDef` object CONTAINS operation in the bytes format! So it is not exactly the same in this sense.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to answer the question directly:

Operations are nodes they just do the computations.

An operation ([tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Operation)): An Operation is a node in a TensorFlow Graph that takes zero or more Tensor objects as input, and produces zero or more Tensor objects as output.

you can see [this](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs20si/syllabus.html)